# ffmpeg to YouTube on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, webcam, youtube

I'm attempting to use a Raspberry Pi Zero to live stream video from a [Logitech C270](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Logitech-C270-HD-Webcam-Black/dp/B003R1O320) to YouTube.

After a bit of Googling I came up with this:

`ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1 -flags +global_header -ar 44100 -ab 10k -s 1280x720 -vcodec h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 250 -vb 1500k -profile:v baseline -r 24 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/STREAM_NAME`

This runs without error and I get lines like this displayed (with gradually decreasing FPS):

`frame=31 fps=1.3 q=0.0 size=0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0`

However, I get nothing streamed to YouTube. Occasionally YouTube will say "Starting" but it gets no further than that. I suspect the problem is that the FPS is too low.

I pretty much followed [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=53936) to install ffmpeg on the Pi.

I have no experience with ffmpeg and I'm wondering if the problem lies with the ffmpeg command I'm using, the lack of power offered by the Pi Zero or my internet connection speed.

Comment: `fps=1.3`. Your device is probably too underpowered to encode fast enough. If the webcam provides H.264 video you **may** be able to stream copy it (`-c copy`) but I have my doubts that it will work. See output of `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0`.

Comment: Current command is defaulting to preset medium, can try `-preset ultrafast`

Answer (score 0):

You should try  with Raspberry Camera. I tried to use USB camera on Raspberry Pi 2, but fps was ok ok for first 2 seconds and than was dropping to 3 fps (however there was something visible on youtube. Now I use Raspberry Pi camera Rev 1.3 and it works very good. Now I would like to use Raspberry Pi Zero too.